# How do I write a matrix inside a flowchart?

Tags: formatting, tikz-matrix, flow-charts

I'm new to LaTeX and I would like to write a matrix inside a flowchart. How do I do this?

The matrix should go in the empty node and concatenated to some text:

[image]

Current method of storing the matrix in a variable does not work:

```
\documentclass...
...
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mat}{\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7
  \end{bmatrix}
\]}
...
{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
...
\node (pro3) [process, below of=pro2] {\mat};


...
\par}
...
\end...
```

Alternatively I could try tabbing the second row characters along but that would be messy.

Please can you assist?

Comment: You have not provided an example that we can compile and test, but I suspect if you edit your definition of `\mat`, to change the `\[` to `$` and the `\]` to `$`, it may work.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes perfect! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method of storing the matrix does work but you are using `\[ ... \]` environment, so you need to prepare the node to typeset such things. This can be done e.g. by adding some `text width`. Of course, if you only want to add a matrix, `\[ ... \]` may not be the best choice, rather, as also [mentioned by Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484491/how-do-i-write-a-matrix-inside-a-flowchart/484492#comment1225080_484491), you may just work with `$...$`, in which case you do not need a key like `text width`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\mat}{\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7
  \end{bmatrix}
\]}
\newcommand{\othermat}{$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7
  \end{bmatrix}$}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,process/.style={draw,fill=orange}]
\node (pro2){test};
\node (pro3) [process, below of=pro2,text width=3cm] {\mat};
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,process/.style={draw,fill=orange}]
\node (pro2){test};
\node (pro3) [process, below of=pro2] {\othermat};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mat}{\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7
  \end{bmatrix}
\]}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (pro3) [%process, below of=pro2
text width=3cm] {\mat};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks {@marmot and @Steven B. Segletes} for explaining